# Giphy TV border radius

Tags: html, css, border, giphy

I put the Giphy TV in my site. Now I want to give it rounded borders, but I dont succeed. Can someone help me out?

https://giphy.com

Giphy TV code:

```
<div id="_giphy_tv"></div>
<script>
var _giphy_tv_tag="giphytrending";
var g = document.createElement('script'); g.type = 'text/javascript'; g.async = true;
g.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'giphy.com/static/js/widgets/tv.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
```

You can also copy it from the site.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some quick research:

```
#asdf-container {
  border-radius: 30px !important;
}
#asdf-wrapper {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Both rules need to be flagged `!important` because that's what they already come in from giphy side.

https://jsfiddle.net/hykoyqo5/

Comment: The height comes from Javascript inline in a style-attribute on the element that has this.

Answer (score 0):

Emmm...

```
#_giphy_tv {
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

?

Comment: Usually the easy approach, this does not solve the problem here.